# SQL join and group items as an array

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.title, tags.name AS tags
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN article_tag_association ON articles.id = article_tag_association.article_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = article_tag_association.tag_id
```

This works OK except it creates a row for each tag an article has, which messes with the limit

e.g.

```
[
 "0" => ["id" => "1", "title" => "test", "tags" => "tag1"],
 "1" => ["id" => "1", "title" => "test", "tags" => "tag2"],
 "2" => ["id" => "2", "title" => "test2", "tags" => "tag1"],
]
```

(only 2 articles but three rows)

is there a way to make it return each article with an array of tags?

something like:

```
[
 "0" => ["id" => "1", "title" => "test", "tags" => ["tag1", "tag2"]],
 "1" => ["id" => "2", "title" => "test2", "tags" => ["tag1"]],
]
```

Comment: can you post your table creation? might be easier to produce string formatted "array"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

by default you cannot return an array. but you can decorate/concatenate your columns to produce an array like string. if its a good idea? depends on your situation. Also please be aware MySQL has some limitations for group_concat (will only return 1024*chars)

anyway just for test purpose you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    concat(
    '[',
    concat('ID => "', articles.id,'"'),
    concat('Title => "', articles.title,'"'),
    concat('Tags => [', GROUP_CONCAT(concat('"',tags.name, '"')), ']'),
    ']'
    ) as Array_String
FROM
    articles
        LEFT JOIN
    article_tag_association ON articles.id = article_tag_association.article_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tags ON tags.id = article_tag_association.tag_id
GROUP BY articles.id
```

this will give you each row as an array, if you want everything in one line put them all under a group_concat.

note: if your result is larger than 1024 char you have to use

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1000000; >> size of your string length
```

PS: haven't tested above code. test it :)

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS tags
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN article_tag_association ON articles.id = article_tag_association.article_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = article_tag_association.tag_id
GROUP BY articles.id
```

You can't return an array in mysql, but you can get this concatenated string and split it into an array on PHP side. You can choose an character used for 'glue' by `GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '#')` for a one that should not appear in any name and thus be safe for splitting into the array.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus SQL has no concept of an array.

Comment: You can't return an array in mysql, but you can get this concatenated string and split it into an array on PHP side

Comment: @BaconBits indeed. So the answer should explain that (so it's fine now ;) )

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I disagree.  That would be pedantic.  StackOverflow isn't where we describe basic concepts of languages.

Comment: @BaconBits that's a point of view, which I respect : I just mean that if a question is about returning an array (which is not possible), and you give an answer with a concatenated string, you should explain why you give THAT answer (which might be perfectly fine). But that's also just a PoV.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus if he rewrites his answer so that it generates something like ['val1','val2',...,'valn'] then this string would basically be an array. not the typical array but a JSON array